# iOS8 - Open podcasts app via website link?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts, html, podcasts.app

One of my clients publishes a number of podcasts.  He would like to add links in our HTML site that would open the Podcast App and load or prompt to load the episode indicated in the link.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208299/launch-podcast-app-with-url-scheme), `feed://podcasturl...` or `pcast://podcasturl...` both work, though slightly differently.

With my tests today, using Chrome for IOS, `feed://` opens up the podcast app with the *"Add a Podcast by URL..."* popup with your podcast feed already populated. All you have to do is press **Subscribe**
If I use Safari, it tries to use a feed reader app, like *Reeder*.

`pcast://` seems to open your podcast so the user can browse the published episodes.

**Note:** the `pcast://` option didn't work for me, possible because this is a private podcast used for testing, and not published to Apple iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Links to the podcast on the iTunes Store will direct iOS users to the Podcasts app automatically.

Comment: But AFAYK I can't use a link to get an episode to load (or a prompt to load episode)?